# From Array with Multiple Inputs to if statement with varnames PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build a function to generate my Menubar.

So far I have following done:

Create an Array with the required Information:

```
$MENU_GEN["MENUNAME"] = array(
    'enabled'=>true,
    'parent'=>true,
    'headline'=>"Wareneingang",
    'access'=>'99,50,25',
    'activelink'=>'$linkvar',
    'buttonvalue'=>'wareneingang',
    'sub_menus'=>array()
);
```

The Problem is i want the 'access' splitted up (since every menupoint can have more or less access levels).

I've tried to splitt the access up like this:

```
$access_split = $item['access'];
$splitter = explode(",",$access_split);
$prefixed_split = preg_filter('/^/','$user_level == ',$splitter);
$buildaccess = implode("||",$prefixed_split);
```

which works great. Now comes my tricky part. I wanna build my if statement from there wich should look like:

```
if($user_level == 99 || $user_level == 50){
```

But if I try to build up everything, the if statement seems to be blank because if change my access level or change the value in the array to something wich even doesnt exists, it just parses everything throu like there is no if statement...

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to format the String to be accepted as code again? (I've read something about the eval() function but I did not get it to work...)

Sorry for my english. Im not a native speaker :'D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can just split the `access` value with:

```
$MENU_GEN["MENUNAME"]['access'] = explode(',' $MENU_GEN["MENUNAME"]['access']);
```

And then use `in_array` for your condition:

```
if(in_array($user_level, $MENU_GEN["MENUNAME"]['access'])) {
```

Comment: Im sorry I think I've been a little unlcear x.x" I want to have my if Statement created. But in_array compares the array content, doesn't it?

I wannt to use the numbers given in acces to create the if($user_level == $number) in addition to make it variable and add more than one $user_level == $number here :) 

Hope its now more clear T_T"

Comment: You want to dynamically generate code while it's running? Not a good idea.

Comment: Well this code will never run on the Internet it just internal. protected by firewalls from intruders so I don't mind if its insecure. ofc i would prefer it to be secure but also i want to avoid databases and the option to always add and mix php/html all the time to generate the navbar.